# How can I display data from PHP arrays in a two-dimensional table?

Tags: php

I have three arrays obtained from DB one health inst name array, another one a delivery data and the last one the date array from dates in delivery data. For example:

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [health_inst_code] => 32HI083 [health_inst_name] => DHM)
[1] => stdClass Object ( [health_inst_code] => 32HI084 [health_inst_name] => THQHSB) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [health_inst_code] => 32HI085 [health_inst_name] => CHCM) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [health_inst_code] => 32HI086 [health_inst_name] => THQHV) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( [health_inst_code] => 32HI087 [health_inst_name] => GHK) 
)



Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 620 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-28 [health_inst_name] => DHM [delivery_institution] => 32HI083 [total_delivery] => 8 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 621 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-27 [health_inst_name] => THQHSB [delivery_institution] => 32HI084 [total_delivery] => 0 ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 619 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-27 [health_inst_name] => GHK [delivery_institution] => 32HI087 [total_delivery] => 3 ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 623 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-27 [health_inst_name] => CHCM [delivery_institution] => 32HI085 [total_delivery] => 0 ) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 625 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-27 [health_inst_name] => THQHV [delivery_institution] => 32HI086 [total_delivery] => 1 ) 
[5] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 523 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-26 [health_inst_name] => THQHSB [delivery_institution] => 32HI084 [total_delivery] => 4 ) 
[6] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 522 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-26 [health_inst_name] => CHCM [delivery_institution] => 32HI085 [total_delivery] => 1 ) 
[7] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 521 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-26 [health_inst_name] => THQHV [delivery_institution] => 32HI086 [total_delivery] => 0 ) 
[8] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 520 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-26 [health_inst_name] => GHK [delivery_institution] => 32HI087 [total_delivery] => 1 ) 
[9] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 518 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-26 [health_inst_name] => DHM [delivery_institution] => 32HI083 [total_delivery] => 7 ) 
[10] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 425 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-25 [health_inst_name] => THQHV [delivery_institution] => 32HI086 [total_delivery] => 1 ) 
[11] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 424 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-25 [health_inst_name] => CHCM [delivery_institution] => 32HI085 [total_delivery] => 0 ) 
[12] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 422 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-25 [health_inst_name] => DHM [delivery_institution] => 32HI083 [total_delivery] => 7 ) 
[13] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 419 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-25 [health_inst_name] => THQHSB [delivery_institution] => 32HI084 [total_delivery] => 2 ) 
[14] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 418 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-25 [health_inst_name] => GHK [delivery_institution] => 32HI087 [total_delivery] => 2 ) 
[15] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 336 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-24 [health_inst_name] => GHK [delivery_institution] => 32HI087 [total_delivery] => 5 ) 
[16] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 337 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-24 [health_inst_name] => DHM [delivery_institution] => 32HI083 [total_delivery] => 6 ) 
[17] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 338 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-24 [health_inst_name] => CHCM [delivery_institution] => 32HI085 [total_delivery] => 0 ) 
[18] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 340 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-24 [health_inst_name] => THQHV [delivery_institution] => 32HI086 [total_delivery] => 0 ) 
[19] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 339 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-24 [health_inst_name] => THQHSB [delivery_institution] => 32HI084 [total_delivery] => 3 ) 
[20] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 246 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-23 [health_inst_name] => GHK [delivery_institution] => 32HI087 [total_delivery] => 0 ) 
[21] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 255 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-23 [health_inst_name] => THQHV [delivery_institution] => 32HI086 [total_delivery] => 1 ) 
[22] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 253 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-23 [health_inst_name] => THQHSB Bathery [delivery_institution] => 32HI084 [total_delivery] => 4 ) 
[23] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 251 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-23 [health_inst_name] => DHM [delivery_institution] => 32HI083 [total_delivery] => 4 ) 
[24] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 249 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-23 [health_inst_name] => CHCM [delivery_institution] => 32HI085 [total_delivery] => 0 ) 
[25] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 197 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-22 [health_inst_name] => DHM [delivery_institution] => 32HI083 [total_delivery] => 10 ) 
[26] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 196 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-22 [health_inst_name] => THQHV [delivery_institution] => 32HI086 [total_delivery] => 0 ) 
[27] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 193 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-22 [health_inst_name] => THQHSB [delivery_institution] => 32HI084 [total_delivery] => 2 ) 
[28] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 194 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-22 [health_inst_name] => GHK [delivery_institution] => 32HI087 [total_delivery] => 1 ) 
[29] => stdClass Object ( [dd_id] => 195 [delivery_date] => 2021-05-22 [health_inst_name] => CHCM [delivery_institution] => 32HI085 [total_delivery] => 1 )
 )



Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [delivery_date] => 2021-05-28 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [delivery_date] => 2021-05-27 ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [delivery_date] => 2021-05-26 )
[3] => stdClass Object ( [delivery_date] => 2021-05-25 ) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( [delivery_date] => 2021-05-24 ) 
[5] => stdClass Object ( [delivery_date] => 2021-05-23 ) 
[6] => stdClass Object ( [delivery_date] => 2021-05-22 ) 
)
```

I want to display the arrays as a two dimensional array in PHP, like the following:

```
             | 2021-05-28 |  2021-05-27 |  2021-05-26|  2021-05-25 |  2021-05-24 |2021-05-23|2021-05-22 |
|            |            |             |            |             |             |          |           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    DHM     |    8       |      -      |     7      |      7      |      6      |    4      |    10
|   THQHSB   |    -       |      0      |     4      |      2      |      3      |    4      |     2
|   CHCM     |    -       |      0      |     1      |      0      |      0      |    0      |     1
|   THQHV    |    -       |      1      |     0      |      1      |      0      |    1      |     0
|   GHK      |    -       |      3      |     1      |      2      |      5      |    0      |     1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

To get the two dim array you wanted, we only needed the second array.

```
<?php
// example code

$array2 = array ( 
"0" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 620, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-28", "health_inst_name" => "DHM", "delivery_institution" => "32HI083", "total_delivery" => 8 ) ,
"1" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 621, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-27", "health_inst_name" => "THQHSB", "delivery_institution" => "32HI084", "total_delivery" => 0 ) ,
"2" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 619, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-27", "health_inst_name" => "GHK", "delivery_institution" => "32HI087", "total_delivery" => 3 ) ,
"3" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 623, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-27", "health_inst_name" => "CHCM", "delivery_institution" => "32HI085", "total_delivery" => 0 ) ,
"4" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 625, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-27", "health_inst_name" => "THQHV", "delivery_institution" => "32HI086", "total_delivery" => 1 ) ,
"5" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 523, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-26", "health_inst_name" => "THQHSB", "delivery_institution" => "32HI084", "total_delivery" => 4 ) ,
"6" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 522, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-26", "health_inst_name" => "CHCM", "delivery_institution" => "32HI085", "total_delivery" => 1 ) ,
"7" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 521, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-26", "health_inst_name" => "THQHV", "delivery_institution" => "32HI086", "total_delivery" => 0 ) ,
"8" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 520, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-26", "health_inst_name" => "GHK", "delivery_institution" => "32HI087", "total_delivery" => 1 ) ,
"9" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 518, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-26", "health_inst_name" => "DHM", "delivery_institution" => "32HI083", "total_delivery" => 7 ) ,
"10" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 425, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-25", "health_inst_name" => "THQHV", "delivery_institution" => "32HI086", "total_delivery" => 1 ) ,
"11" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 424, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-25", "health_inst_name" => "CHCM", "delivery_institution" => "32HI085", "total_delivery" => 0 ) ,
"12" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 422, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-25", "health_inst_name" => "DHM", "delivery_institution" => "32HI083", "total_delivery" => 7 ) ,
"13" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 419, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-25", "health_inst_name" => "THQHSB", "delivery_institution" => "32HI084", "total_delivery" => 2 ) ,
"14" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 418, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-25", "health_inst_name" => "GHK", "delivery_institution" => "32HI087", "total_delivery" => 2 ) ,
"15" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 336, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-24", "health_inst_name" => "GHK", "delivery_institution" => "32HI087", "total_delivery" => 5 ) ,
"16" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 337, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-24", "health_inst_name" => "DHM", "delivery_institution" => "32HI083", "total_delivery" => 6 ) ,
"17" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 338, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-24", "health_inst_name" => "CHCM", "delivery_institution" => "32HI085", "total_delivery" => 0 ) ,
"18" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 340, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-24", "health_inst_name" => "THQHV", "delivery_institution" => "32HI086", "total_delivery" => 0 ) ,
"19" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 339, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-24", "health_inst_name" => "THQHSB", "delivery_institution" => "32HI084", "total_delivery" => 3 ) ,
"20" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 246, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-23", "health_inst_name" => "GHK", "delivery_institution" => "32HI087", "total_delivery" => 0 ) ,
"21" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 255, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-23", "health_inst_name" => "THQHV", "delivery_institution" => "32HI086", "total_delivery" => 1 ) ,
"22" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 253, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-23", "health_inst_name" => "THQHSB",  "delivery_institution" => "32HI084", "total_delivery" => 4 ) ,
"23" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 251, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-23", "health_inst_name" => "DHM", "delivery_institution" => "32HI083", "total_delivery" => 4 ) ,
"24" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 249, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-23", "health_inst_name" => "CHCM", "delivery_institution" => "32HI085", "total_delivery" => 0 ) ,
"25" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 197, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-22", "health_inst_name" => "DHM", "delivery_institution" => "32HI083", "total_delivery" => 10 ) ,
"26" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 196, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-22", "health_inst_name" => "THQHV", "delivery_institution" => "32HI086", "total_delivery" => 0 ) ,
"27" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 193, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-22", "health_inst_name" => "THQHSB", "delivery_institution" => "32HI084", "total_delivery" => 2 ) ,
"28" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 194, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-22", "health_inst_name" => "GHK", "delivery_institution" => "32HI087", "total_delivery" => 1 ) ,
"29" => (object) array ( "dd_id" => 195, "delivery_date" => "2021-05-22", "health_inst_name" => "CHCM", "delivery_institution" => "32HI085", "total_delivery" => 1 ),
 );

$twodim=[];
foreach ($array2 as $n => $data) {
    if (!isset($twodim[$data->delivery_date])) $twodim[$data->delivery_date] = array();
    if (!isset($twodim[$data->delivery_date][$data->health_inst_name])) $twodim[$data->delivery_date][$data->health_inst_name] = 0;
    $twodim[$data->delivery_date][$data->health_inst_name] += intVal($data->total_delivery) ;

}

print_r($twodim);
```

This will give you the following output, that you can easily manipulate into a table like you illustrated in your question:

```
Array
(
    [2021-05-28] => Array
        (
            [DHM] => 8
        )

    [2021-05-27] => Array
        (
            [THQHSB] => 0
            [GHK] => 3
            [CHCM] => 0
            [THQHV] => 1
        )

    [2021-05-26] => Array
        (
            [THQHSB] => 4
            [CHCM] => 1
            [THQHV] => 0
            [GHK] => 1
            [DHM] => 7
        )

    [2021-05-25] => Array
        (
            [THQHV] => 1
            [CHCM] => 0
            [DHM] => 7
            [THQHSB] => 2
            [GHK] => 2
        )

    [2021-05-24] => Array
        (
            [GHK] => 5
            [DHM] => 6
            [CHCM] => 0
            [THQHV] => 0
            [THQHSB] => 3
        )

    [2021-05-23] => Array
        (
            [GHK] => 0
            [THQHV] => 1
            [THQHSB] => 4
            [DHM] => 4
            [CHCM] => 0
        )

    [2021-05-22] => Array
        (
            [DHM] => 10
            [THQHV] => 0
            [THQHSB] => 2
            [GHK] => 1
            [CHCM] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: The first `!isset()` is unnecessary.  Parent levels do not need to be declared before child levels in php.  If this job is how to get a running count of data, we already have duplicates for this on Stack Overflow.